# Installed Ubuntu onto SD card, booting via UEFI, Grub problems

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I want 15.10 on my Thinkpad Yoga laptop, but installed on the SD card. I've installed it successfully, but when I go to boot, the the Grub flashes an error message too quickly to read, then drops into a Grub command prompt. If I try to select the SD card as the boot device from the boot options menu, it doesn't go anywhere.

I installed the system on the SD card using manual partitioning, creating a root partition and a swap partition. Do I need to have created an EFI partition on the SD card?

Is there any way to catch the error message that Grub is flashing up?

EDIT:
I tried re-installing, but putting an EFI partition on the SD card, but after this I don't get a grub prompt at all. And the Windows partition has shredded the bitlocker key (which I could recover from the MS recovery site)

Answer (score 0):

Some computers can't read their SD cards from their firmware, which means that you can't install boot loaders or OS kernels there. If this is the issue, the solution is to move part of your installation -- the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) and a separate Ubuntu `/boot` partition -- to your regular hard disk (or I'm guessing an SSD for a Yoga). You can keep the rest of the Ubuntu installation on the SD card, but these components must be on a disk that the firmware can read.

As to catching the GRUB message, try doing a video recording. Even most cell phones these days can do that. You can then play it back a frame at a time.